# flask does not recognize post request

Tags: python, html, flask

i am working on a flask project.

i want to retrieve data from the form and store them in database.

but the server does not recognize the post request so i cannot retrieve or store any data

> html code

```
<div class="container-lg p-3 border mt-6 mb-3" style="max-width: 460px;">
  <form action="{{ url_for('registration') }}"  method="POST" class="ui form" id="add-user" >
    <dl class="mt-2 form-group">
      <dt><label for="name">Full Name</label></dt>
      <dd>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control bg-white"
          name="name"
          id="name"s
          placeholder="Enter your name"
          required
          autofocus
        />
      </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="mt-2 form-group">
      <dt><label for="email">Email Address</label></dt>
      <dd>
        <input
          type="email"
          class="form-control bg-white"
          name="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="Enter your email"
          required
        />
      </dd>
    </dl>

    <div class="mt-2 form-group bg-white" onkeydown="remove_placeholder()">
      <label for="question-input-101" class="d-block mb-2">Skills</label>
      <div
        class="topic-input-container tag-input-container js-tag-input-container"
      >
        <div
          class="tag-input form-control js-tag-input-wrapper clearfix position-relative bg-white"
        >
          <ul class="js-tag-input-selected-tags">
            <li
              class="d-none topic-tag-action f6 float-left js-tag-input-tag js-template"
            >
              <span class="js-placeholder-tag-name"></span>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="delete-topic-button f5 no-underline ml-2 js-remove"
                tabindex="-1"
              >

              </button>
              <input
                type="hidden"
                name="answers[101][selections][]"
                class="js-topic-input"
                value=""
              />
            </li>
          </ul>

          <auto-complete
            src=""
            aria-owns="tag-popup"
            role="combobox"
            aria-haspopup="listbox"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              id="question-input-101"
              class="tag-input-inner form-control bg-white shorter d-inline-block p-0 my-1 border-0"
              autocomplete="off"
              autofocus=""
              aria-owns="tag-popup"
              spellcheck="false"
              aria-autocomplete="list"
              aria-controls="tag-popup"
              placeholder="Space separated"
              maxlength="40"
            />
            <ul
              class="suggester border width-full bg-white left-0"
              id="tag-popup"
              style="top: 100%;"
              hidden=""
              role="listbox"
            ></ul>
          </auto-complete>

          <input
            type="hidden"
            name="answers[101][choice]"
            id="answers_101_choice"
            value="474"
            class="form-control"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="mt-3 note">
      What languages, frameworks, technologies, or skills do you have/know?
    </p>
    <p class="note" style="margin-top: -6px">
      e.g. html, python, machine-learning.
    </p>

    <button
      class="btn btn-lg mt-4 btn-blue btn-block"
      type="submit"
      onclick="parse()"
    >
      Add yourself
    </button>
    <div class="ui success message">
      <div class="header">Registered Successfully!</div>
      <p>
        Now, please check your inbox and verify your email.<br />
        <b>Note:</b> You won't appear in the search results unless you
        verify your email.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui error message">
      <div class="header">Something Went Wrong!</div>
      <p id="error-message"></p>
    </div>
  </form> </prev>
```

i use flask and sqllite as code below

> python code "register function"

```
@app.route("/registration", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def registration():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if not request.form.get("name"):
            return apology("you must provide name")
        elif not request.form.get("email"):
            return apology("you must provide email")
        elif not request.form.get("answers[101][selections][]"):
            return apology("you must provide skills")

        else:
            name = request.form.get("name")
            email = request.form.get("email")
            skills = request.form.get("answers[101][selections][]")

            db.execute("Insert into students(name, skills, email) Values(:name,:skills,:email)", name=name, skills=skills, email=email)
            return render_template("registration.html")

    else:
        return render_template("registration.html")
```

i`v tried many things and searched for similar problems but that could not help my case

thanks in advance !

> update

here is server response

```
* Serving Flask app "application.py" (lazy loading)
* Environment: development
* Debug mode: off
* Running on https://c4c2d2de-af5f-4a37-b685-424eae62c49b-ide.cs50.xyz:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.141.75 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:13:59] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.141.75 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:13:59] "GET /static/css/lib/frameworks-41c2037bf12f1e46d8f08b88a04a8d8f.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.114.150 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:13:59] "GET /static/css/lib/github-bb09139146955473c2e2a9015b3d8cd6.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.94.189 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:13:59] "GET /static/js/lib/frameworks-369fa3dc.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.152.245 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:00] "GET /static/js/index.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.202.213 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:00] "GET /static/js/lib/github-bootstrap-ddb380c5.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.202.213 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:02] "GET /registration HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.202.213 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/css/lib/frameworks-41c2037bf12f1e46d8f08b88a04a8d8f.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.114.150 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/css/lib/github-bb09139146955473c2e2a9015b3d8cd6.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.94.189 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/css/custom.css HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.152.245 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/js/lib/github-bootstrap-ddb380c5.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.141.75 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/js/lib/frameworks-369fa3dc.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.94.189 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/js/submit.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.202.213 - - [23/Dec/2019 15:14:03] "GET /static/js/remove_placeholder.js HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Comment: "but the server does not recognize the post request" - what does it mean? how a server can dare not to recognize a request? what kind of server is that? 

p.s. pleas share your server output.

Comment: @marmeladze okay i will update the post

Comment: @marmeladze i updated it and there is no post methods as in response as you see

Comment: hm.. i guess CORS problem. But im not sure with out browser console output. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/log

Comment: Do yo have any error messages? Didn't see any from your server response. I just copied most of the code, and tested about the request and post. I think they are working.I can see the input which just simply returned from html.

Comment: What happens if you remove `onclick="parse()"`?

Comment: Open up the Network tab of the browser's developer tools  then submit the form. Do you see the browser making a request?
Also what is the response of this request?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith parse function parses the input to the server backend , i opened the consol and found out that there was a problem in the url of the server.